# Mapping data to a new array resulting in wrong data in a specific date range

Tags: javascript

I have a functionality in the snippet that takes an array of objects and re-map that into a new array with new fields and calculations. The calculation is done each day on a range of dates provided from another array of dates batch.
The functionality needs an interval of time to do the calculation and this is what it is failing now. Given an interval, results are shown wrong.

```js
const mockData = [
  // INCOMPLETE
  {
    id: "C1-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: null,
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T12:15:00.000Z",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05T01:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: "C2-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  },
  {
    id: "C3-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  },
  {
    id: "C4-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: null,
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T12:15:00.000Z",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05T01:00:00.000Z"
  },
  // DROPOUT_PRESCREENER
  {
    id: "C5-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER",
    eligible: false,
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  },
  // REJECTED_PRESCREENER
  {
    id: "C6-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "REJECTED_PRESCREENER",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  },
  // Out of range
  {
    id: "C7-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "REJECTED_PRESCREENER",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-02T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  }
];

const assignLabel = (statusType, eligible) => {
  if (statusType === "INCOMPLETE") return "pending";
  if (statusType === "REJECTED_PRESCREENER") return "ineligible";
  if (statusType === "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER" && eligible) return "eligible";
  if (statusType === "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER" && !eligible) return "abandoned";
  return "completed";
};

// This dates are generated from a fuction bases on which dates range we need
// In this cas is just one day
const batches = [new Date("2020-12-02T00:00:00.000Z")];

const screeningNumbersCalculations = () => {
  const results = [];

  batches.forEach((t) => {
    let matchingStatusesTime = mockData.filter((s) => {
      return (
        new Date(s.statusFrom) <= t &&
        (s.statusTo == null || t <= new Date(s.statusTo))
      );
    });

    matchingStatusesTime.forEach((ms) => {
      const r = {
        days: [t.toISOString().split("T")[0]],
        studyId: ms.studyId,
        siteId: ms.siteId,
        screeningStage: "SELF_ASSESSMENT",
        label: assignLabel(ms.statusType, ms.eligible),
        total: 1
      };

      const key = `${r.days}${r.studyId}${r.siteId}`;
      if (results[key]) results[key].total++;
      else results[key] = r;
    });
  });

  return Object.values(results);
};

const screeningNumbers = screeningNumbersCalculations();

console.log(JSON.stringify(screeningNumbers, null, 2));
```

The snippet for simplicity uses just one day as that is a possible scenario.

the result of the functionality as you see is 2 objects with wrong total but the expected result is as follows

```
 [
  {
    "days": [
      "2020-12-01"
    ],
    "studyId": "TBX4",
    "siteId": null,
    "screeningStage": "SELF_ASSESSMENT",
    "label": "pending",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "days": [
      "2020-12-01"
    ],
    "studyId": "TBX4",
    "siteId": "USA-1",
    "screeningStage": "SELF_ASSESSMENT",
    "label": "pending",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "days": [
      "2020-12-01"
    ],
    "studyId": "TBX4",
    "siteId": "USA-1",
    "screeningStage": "SELF_ASSESSMENT",
    "label": "ineligible",
    "total": 1
  },
   {
    "days": [
      "2020-12-01"
    ],
    "studyId": "TBX4",
    "siteId": "USA-1",
    "screeningStage": "SELF_ASSESSMENT",
    "label": "abandoned",
    "total": 1
  }
]
```

The result above for that day has 4 items because I need to aggregate in one object for the same day from the mockData objects by unique StudyId and Status and then by siteId.

The goal is that on that day is to show how many items are in a specific status with a label.

In this scenario, we just considering `INCOMPLETE` which has the label `pending`.
Also we have the same **study** but a different **site** so will be 2 objects as the sites which contain the totals for the status with the same study.

Not sure how to achieve my result as not getting any data back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date filter is not correct. The time `statusTo` can be `null` but you use the `&&` condition.

There aren't any elements in `matchingStatusesTime`.

**UPDATE v2**

```js
const mockData = [
  

// INCOMPLETE
  {
    id: "C1-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: null,
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T12:15:00.000Z",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05T01:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: "C2-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  },
  {
    id: "C3-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  },
  {
    id: "C4-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: null,
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T12:15:00.000Z",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05T01:00:00.000Z"
  },
  // DROPOUT_PRESCREENER
  {
    id: "C5-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER",
    eligible: false,
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  },
  // REJECTED_PRESCREENER
  {
    id: "C6-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "REJECTED_PRESCREENER",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  },
  // Out of range
  {
    id: "C7-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "REJECTED_PRESCREENER",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-02T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  }
];

const assignLabel = (statusType, eligible) => {
    if (statusType === 'INCOMPLETE') return 'pending';
    if (statusType === 'REJECTED_PRESCREENER') return 'ineligible';
    if (statusType === 'DROPOUT_PRESCREENER' && eligible) return 'eligible';
    if (statusType === 'DROPOUT_PRESCREENER' && !eligible) return 'abandoned';
    return 'completed';
};

// This dates are generated from a fuction bases on which dates range we need
// In this cas is just one day
const batches = [new Date('2020-12-02T00:00:00.000Z')]

const screeningNumbersCalculations = () => {
    const results = [];

    batches.forEach(t => {
        let matchingStatusesTime = mockData.filter(s => {
            return new Date(s.statusFrom) <= t && (s.statusTo == null || t <= new Date(s.statusTo));
        });
          
        matchingStatusesTime.forEach(ms => {
            const r = {
                days: [t.toISOString().split('T')[0]],
                studyId: ms.studyId,
                siteId: ms.siteId,
                screeningStage: 'SELF_ASSESSMENT',
                label: assignLabel(ms.statusType, ms.eligible),
                total: 1,
            };
            
            const key = `${r.days}${r.studyId}${r.siteId}${r.label}`;
            if (results[key])
                results[key].total++;
            else
                results[key] = r;
        });
    });

    return Object.values(results);
};

const screeningNumbers = screeningNumbersCalculations();

console.log(JSON.stringify(screeningNumbers, null, 2));
```

Comment: Should I use || then?  
I need to include the null as well

Comment: I did an edit bu still the total is not right

Comment: why use statusTo? if ```statusTo="2020-11-30"``` and ```statusFrom="2020-12-02"```, is it included?

Comment: The statusTo is becasue in the dates batches we can have more dates and statusTo means when that items changed status.
If we have a range of dates which goes from 1 to 5 for example and one item has statusTo 5 that item is calculated to the date 4 but secluded on day 5 because the status changed to something else. The date batches are generated in an interval of dates in my case I just need one day but could be also between 2 dates.
We can also have items changing status the same day so the latest statusFrom has to be considered for it then and exclude earlier same items from the calcs

Comment: The satusTo cannot be earlier then statusFrom

Comment: you still leave it null ```r.statusTo = r.statusTo ? new Date(r.statusTo).getTime() : null;```, conditions will be as follows ```return (s.statusFrom <= t.time && (statusTo == null || t.time < s.statusTo));```. I see your update worked

Comment: Yes I see data but the calculation is wrong. If you see what I'm expecting is different of what I'm getting

Comment: I tried your suggestion but doesn't work giving back again []

Comment: That worked better but generated another issue as I can show in this snippet
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-rubin-x4n4e0?file=/src/index.js
I should see 4 objects with calls but I see 2 and the second one is wrong as there are no 2 incomplete with siteId USA-1. 
Here the expected result I also will edit my question with the same
https://pastebin.com/4AgBXEDQ

Comment: Your expected result is grouped add ```label```, add ```label``` to ```key``` to split it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246245/discussion-between-jakub-and-minh-tan).